# What is the full form of "SPI" in the Spring 3 type conversion system?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, terminology

What does the acronym "SPI" stand for in the [Spring 3 type conversion API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

SPI=Service Provider Interface. This is the way you define extensions or customizations

Answer (score 6):

FYI, [Service Provider Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface) is not a Spring framework specific term.

From Wikipedia,

> Service Provider Interface (SPI) is an API intended to be implemented or extended by a third party. It can be used to enable framework extension and replaceable components.