# What's means SPI on Spring-Cache CacheManager

Tags: java, spring

```java
package org.springframework.cache;

/**
 * Spring's central cache manager SPI.
 * Allows for retrieving named {@link Cache} regions.
 *
 * @author Costin Leau
 * @since 3.1
 */
public interface CacheManager { ... }
```

what is means by SPI?

is that "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the full form of "SPI" in the Spring 3 type conversion system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898452/what-is-the-full-form-of-spi-in-the-spring-3-type-conversion-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SPI** =: **S**ervice **P**rovider **I**nterface

[from wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface)

> Service Provider Interface (SPI) is an API intended to be implemented
>   or extended by a third party. It can be used to enable framework
>   extension and replaceable components.